# Passing open Generic Delegate as Callback

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

Probably I'm searching for some wrong Keyword, but I couldn't find anything on this matter: I'm tinkering around with WPF MVVM and I'm now at the Point, I'm looking for a solution to give a ViewModel the possibility to request the Container to change to anhother ViewModel.
My approach is to pass a Callback to the created ViewModel, which is held on the Abstract BaseClass and can called, if desired. The method in the Container looks like this:

```
    private void ApplyViewModel<T>()
        where T : ViewModelBase
    {
        _exHandler.HandledAction(
            () =>
            {
                var vm = _viewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<T>();
                vm.ApplyViewModel = ApplyViewModel<T>;
                CurrentContent = vm;
            });
    }
```

The interesting point is the second Line, where I pass the Method itself to the ViewModel.
For this matter, I created also a Delegate:

```
public delegate void ApplyViewModelDelegate<T>()
    where T : ViewModelBase;
```

The problem lies now in the definition of the Callback in the ViewModelBase: It seems not possible to define it as an open generic Delegate. So I would like to create a Property with the following Signature:

```
public ApplyViewModelDelegate<T> ApplyViewModel { get; set; }
```

Is there kindahow a possibility to pass a Delegate as open generic Type, until I'd really like to call it with a specific Type?

Edit:
If I define the Property like this:

```
public ApplyViewModelDelegate<ViewModelBase> SwitchToViewModel { get; set; }
```

I can assign the Property from the Container, but my final idea would be to call this Property to target a specific ViewModel. For example, a Command could look like this:

```
    public ViewModelCommand ToTest2
    {
        get
        {
            return new ViewModelCommand(
                "To Test2",
                new ActionCommand(() =>
                {
                    SwitchToViewModel<Test2ViewModel>();
                }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not declare property as ApplyViewModelDelegate<ViewModelBase>?

Comment: Hm can you elaborate, what you mean?

Comment: declare property as public ApplyViewModelDelegate<ViewModelBase> ApplyViewModelHandler {get;set;}. Then you can assign reference to your ApplyViewModel<T> method to this property.

Comment: I could assign it then, but I'd like to call it with a specific ViewModel, not the base one. I edited to show what I mean.